# Is it possible to have a checkbox contain a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am hoping to achieve is when I tick a checkbox it applies an integer to a total. When it is unchecked, the default value is zero.

Comment: Is yours a Java or a Javascript question? Please be accurate with your tags.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With html:

```
<input id="my_checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<div id="my_total">0.00</div>
```

and jQuery script on domReady:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#my_checkbox").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#my_total').html('333.45');
        } else {
            $('#my_total').html('0.00');
        };
    }).trigger('change');
});
```